# Можно ли употреблять слова "задом" и "передом"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли к группе людей, или к отдельно взятому человеку обратиться: "Повернитесь ко мне ПЕРЕДОМ" или  "повернитесь ко мне ЗАДОМ". Можно ли употреблять именно слова "задом" и "передом"?

Answer (score 2):

Не могу представить ситуацию, в которой оправдано сочетание передом/задом с обращением на Вы/вы. Тут либо "Эй, ты, повернись-ка ко мне передом! (А ну, все повернулись ко мне задом!)" - либо так, как уже предложено предыдущим оратором.

Comment: Тут бываает трудно понять, кто предыдущий... Показываете пальцем.

Answer (score 1):

Так обращаться неприлично. Лучше: пожалуйста, повернитесь ко мне лицом/спиной.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что иметь ввиду под "можно". С точки зрения грамматики -  вполне. А ято касается этикета - то это вопрос не совсем лингвистический. Я думаю, что в разговорной речи - вполне уместно. Уж человеку, с которым Вы на ты, вполне возможно. Ну а что касается высокого стиля, то лучше действительно воздержаться от употребления, ибо могут неправильно понять. 
Вообще "задом и передом" это более былинные слова, сейчас могут восприниматься как эвфемизмы, поэтому и и возникают сомнения.

Comment: Извините, когда писал, ваш ответ не был виден.

Comment: Какие проблемы? ))) Я вообще часто не читаю чужие ответы, если уверен в своем.

Comment: behemothus, согласитесь,что это грубо-фамильярное обращение, даже по отношению к человеку, с которым на "ты". Другое дело. так сказать в шутку, но опять-таки близким людям.

Comment: Не могу согласиться.

Comment: (+) Вот я представил, как тридцать лет назад дочке косичку заплетал. Ну что, я скажу "спиной"? Да ни в жисть.

Comment: Это ребенок. А что, то же самое вы скажете взрослым на полным серьезе, даже близким?

Comment: Да какая разница?! Если человек близкий, то эвфемизмов не требуется.

Comment: Избушка, избушка, повернись ко мне передом, а к лесу - задом!

Comment: Только нет "повернись", а "стань". "Повернись" - это уже не былинный язык.